# Django Page Not Found / No Post matches the given query

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I won't go to blog/develops but I get this error:
Page not found (404)
No Post matches the given query.

### You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

I don't understand why I am getting this error and how can I solve it.

This is my urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name="post_list"),
    path('<str:adres>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
    path('develops/', views.develop_list, name='develop_list')
]
```

This is views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render , get_object_or_404 , redirect
from .models import Post
from .forms import EmailAbonelikForm

def post_list(request):
    best_post = Post.objects.filter(best=True)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(best=False, dev = False)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts':posts , 'best_post':best_post})

def post_detail(request, adres):
    posts = get_object_or_404(Post , adres=adres)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailAbonelikForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('post_list')
    else:
        form = EmailAbonelikForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'posts':posts , 'form':form})

def develop_list(request):
    posts_dev = Post.objects.filter(dev=True)
    return render(request, 'blog/develop_list.html', {'posts_dev':posts_dev})
```

This is develop_list.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container mt-4">
    {% for post in posts_dev %}
    <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.adres %}" style="color:black;">
        <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width:700px;">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="/media/{{ post.photo }}" class="card-img">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{post.title}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{post.title}}</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Etkinlik Tarihi: {{post.title}}</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

How can I see blog/develops.

Comment: So just to clarify, you are trying to visit the ```develops/``` url? Please also share the code for the template ```develop_list.html``` - the error might be in there.

Comment: I added html file. And yeah I want to go blabla/blog/develops/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Django's url dispatcher is actually attempting to route you to the `post_detail` view. Consider these url patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:adres>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
    path('develops/', views.develop_list, name='develop_list')
]
```

When you visit `blog/develops/`, Django thinks you are passing in a `str` argument `develops` to your first url pattern. To mitigate this, you can either remove the `post-detail` pattern and append it after your other patterns at the end of the file:

```
urlpatterns += path('<str:adres>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail')
```

Or, change the detail pattern so that it has something else in front of named argument:

```
path('detail/<str:adres>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail')
```

Either one should make your patterns behave as intended, but I would recommend the latter option for cleanliness's sake.